# Masked input field is being cleared if it is not completely entered

Tags: html

```
<input id="format_ThisFormat" name="format_ThisFormat" type="hidden" value="##-##-##-##" />
```

So, I know this much to go on, but basically, my issue is that the input field is being cleared if the complete mask isn't being entered (For example, if just "12-44" is being input, the field will clear, but if "12-34-56-78" is entered, the field will stay.  I want the ability to allow for partial inputs.  Any ideas how I can edit this line to accomplish what I am trying to achieve? I'm assuming it's an issue with this line, I'm not just going to post thousands and thousands of lines of code because it won't make any sense, custom API in visual basic SPA.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a event listener and check if the input is valid:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('format_ThisFormat');

input.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  if(!e.target.value.match(/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/g)){
    e.target.value = '';
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="format_ThisFormat" name="format_ThisFormat" type="text" />
```

Comment: I want it to be sumbittable even if the right pattern is not entered, but with my current method, if a pattern of "12-34" is entered it is cleared. I don't want that to happen, I want it to be sumbittable with "12-34"

Comment: The pattern I am using ```value="##-##-##-##"``` is just a mask to guide the user, but I don't want it be a requirement.

Comment: and what if it match it? Clear the field or mark it as valid?

Comment: Mark it as valid.  Though valid isn't really the correct word.  This input field is for searching, so with my current method (Listed in the original post) it will only allow for an exact mask search.  I want to allow for partial mask searches, though still showing the entire mask when the user is typing in the field (if that makes sense)

Comment: When I say "it will only allow" I mean the input field will clear if an exact match isn't entered.